# Inserir ID em outro campo da mesma tabela no momento do INSERT

Tags: php, mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, mysqli

Estou na seguinte situação, andei pesquisando net a fora e encontrei auxílios semelhantes mas não o que realmente preciso saber e nem sei se é possível!

Vamos lá! Teria alguma maneira de eu colocar o número da ID que será inserida na query INSERT e clonar ele para outro campo da mesma tabela mas, isso tudo na mesma query?

---

**tabela:**

usuarios

**campos:**

id (Auto increment)

id_membro

---

**Gostaria de fazer uma query onde o número que será gerado no campo id também fosse colocado no campo id_membro.**

Agradeço!

Comment: Ok, editado....

Comment: Logo asseguir ao `INSERT`, não poderá efetuar um `UPDATE`?

Comment: Sim era o que eu iria fazer, mas queria saber se era possível executar tudo no mesma query, pensando em optimizar o código!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crie uma `TRIGGER AFTER INSERT` para realizar um `UPDATE`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER new_loaner_added
AFTER INSERT ON usuarios
FOR EACH ROW
  UPDATE usuarios
     SET id_membro = NEW.id
   WHERE id = NEW.id;
```

---

> [`TRIGGER`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/triggers.html)
>
> A trigger is a named database object that is associated with a table, and that activates when a particular event occurs for the table.

Em tradução livre:

> Uma trigger é um objeto nomeado da base de dados que é associado a uma tabela, e é ativada quando um evento em particular ocorre para a tabela.

Comment: Ok vou tentar adaptar no meu código e retorno! Não sabia que era possível executar um UPDATE na mesma query

Comment: Como adaptaria em um INSERT comum? pois tenho mais valores a serem inseridos os exemplos que dei acima somente com 1 campo foram hipotéticos, Um exemplo do que tenho : "INSERT INTO usuários (pca_membro,pca_email,pca_nome) VALUES ('{$id_resgatado_auto_increment}','{$email}','{$nome}')";

Comment: Tranquilo mas de qualquer maneira a informação foi útil, vou optar por fazer um update posterior mesmo.